# it is possible to video live wallpaper in android application?

Tags: android, video, live-wallpaper

it is possible to video live wallpaper in android application?
anybody help me and perfect way for implemented in live wallpaper.

Thanks!

Comment: Try reading [here.](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-set-a-video-as-live-wallpaper-on-any-android-device/) This might help

Comment: GO through this [Link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html) .This link gives you the basics for live wallpaper in android.
Then this [Link](http://ikaruga2.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/video-live-wallpaper-part-1/) gives you the proper way to create a video live wallpaper.