# How to play video as live wallpaper android?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Does anyone know **`how to play .mp4 video as live wallpaper`**?

I searched a lot, but couldn't find the solution. I just found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307723/it-is-possible-to-video-live-wallpaper-in-android-application) but I am not getting any idea from it.

Please help me if you have any idea regarding this concept.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=804720  have a look at this

Comment: http://ikaruga2.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/video-live-wallpaper-part-1/ if you go thourgh this link you will get some idea.

Comment: sample codes for above links are available here https://github.com/frankandrobot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After spending 3 days finally I run [this project in eclipse](https://github.com/frankandrobot/GLWallpaperVideoDemo).

I am sharing the steps as it may help others:

Firstly, the most important thing is that `Your project path` and `ndk path` should not contain spaces else you will have problems following these steps. I also faced problems with it so please remove the spaces, if any.

**For example :-**

> android ndk/Live wallpaper

**replace it with**

> androidndk/Livewallpaper

**Following are steps :-**

1) Install NDK from [Android NDK page](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)
(I used Ubuntu OS)

2) Install `plugins` for NDK ( https://dl-sl.google.com/android/eclipse/ )

3) Open your terminal and go to your project directory path

**For Example :-** `/yourprojectname$`

4) Now from your project directory path write Your Android NDk path

**For Example :-**

```
 /home/rainc/android_setup/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-build
```

And Press Enter. This will give you a `.so` file which means the library file has been generated..

You have done it successfully. If you are getting error(s) here then the installation and the other steps might be having error(s).

Following links helped me in my research:

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407224/how-to-install-and-build-ndk-with-eclipse)

[Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938098/ndk-build-error)

[Third](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin)

And also thanks to Lazy Ninja for helping me.

Comment: For eclipse users you may need to rename "lib" to "libs". For windows users you also need to follow these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113993/error-1-libavcodec-so-file-format-not-recognized-android-gl-live-wallpaper/17700708#17700708 . Finally, you may compile with ndk straight from Eclipse by right-clicking the project > Android Tools > Add native support...

Comment: Hi @Prince i tried to follow this steps but i am unable to run this app. Do i also need to replace ffmpeg library as well?

Comment: @Divyu nop brother. no need to replace ffmpeg library. what issue are you facing ?

Comment: you can have my skype id divya221189. I followed all the steps but still i am getting error no launcher activity found and my app is getting crashed. Hey i need your help Please do help.

Comment: @Divyu I am busy with other work, I can help you later.

Comment: prince actually i am confused about the fourth step when i open project directory path .. my ndk is in some other directory so i am not getting how will i build ndk

Comment: Hey i am done with all steps and i am getting this error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service frankandrobot.glwallpapervideodemo.com

Comment: @Divyu Sorry for late reply. Did you resolve your error / issue ?

Comment: @Divyu what issue are you facing ??

Answer (score 7):

You are up on a good challenge, unless you are familiar with android ndk.
 There is the library `ffmpeg` which will save you some time.
A tutorial on [Video Live Wallpaper here](http://ikaruga2.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/video-live-wallpaper-part-1/).
Go through part 1 -4.
And here is a [link](https://github.com/frankandrobot/GLWallpaperVideoDemo) of the project code.
Hope it will help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for reply i configuring NDK in my eclipse. Let me try it thanks.