# How to install Android NDK

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to use FastCV, https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv/setting-developer-environment. It tells me that I need to install Android NDK. I did that and put it in the place that it told me to.

I then try: cd /cygdrive/c/Development/Android/android-ndk-r6/samples/san-angeles

And it tells me that there is no file or folder by that name.

I then try the command ndk-build and it tells me that there is no command by that name.

Note: there is a cygwin section in the "How to get started" section, but it says that it is not relevant for mac users.

Here is another part that I don't understand:

```
MAC: Update $path variable to point to the ndk directory. Modify the /Users/<login-name>/.tcshrcfile to set the path by adding /Users/<login-name>/Development/Android/android-ndk-r6. Along with the changes applied in the section 'Android SDK Downloader' you will have:

set path = ( $path /Developer/usr/bin /Users//Development/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools /Users//Development/Android/android-ndk-r6 )
```

I have NO idea what is being asked of me here.

I just want to solve this, so I can actually start doing things.

Edit: I think (emphasis on I think) that I misread the instructions about cygwin. So I don't need to do the ndk-build commands. However, I still don't know what the instructions mean about the path stuff

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14273781/1405983). hope it helps.

Comment: I tried, but I can't understand the instructions.

Comment: You're using cygwin on a mac?

Answer (score 0):

You should download NDK for Mac OS, the 64-bit version can be found [here](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2). Note that today we don't use r6 anymore, the current version is r9.

NDK is distributed as a plain compressed archive. Mac will open it for you and extract all files. Copy this whole tree wherever you like, and add the top directory to ${path} environment variable.

Let's say you decided to copy extracted NDK into `/Users/user678392/ndk`. Then you should try

```
cd /Users/user678392/ndk/samples/san-angeles
ndk-build
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't know what "Copy this whole tree wherever you like, and add the top directory to ${path} environment variable" means

Comment: This doesn't work, because there is no ndk-build in the san-angleses directory.

Comment: Try `../../ndk-build`