# NDK Android: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file

Tags: android, android-ndk

Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /Users/myusername/jni/Android.mk
/Users/myusername/Android/Development/android-ndk-r9/build/core/add-application.mk:176: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

Lots of people seem to have this error. However, none of help seems to be helping. If you have suggestions, please make them concrete and specific.

Comment: You probably run `ndk-build` from `/Users/myusername` directory. Usually, you should run the command from the root directory of your Android project. Usually, this is not the `/Users/myusername` directory.

Comment: then how does it know where the ndk-build script is?

Comment: You can provide the full path to `ndk-build`.

Comment: What did you do to receive `Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file` message that started your question?

Comment: ./ndk-build is what I typed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Android NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558682/how-to-install-android-ndk)