# Android: Setting Captured Video as Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, video, live-wallpaper, mediarecorder, video-recording

I've captured video using `MediaRecorder` into sd card. Now i want to set my saved video as live wallpaper programatically. Any idea on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are up on a good challenge, unless you are familiar with android ndk.
There is the library `ffmpeg` which will save you some time.

[You can follow my answer to get started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256412/how-to-play-video-as-live-wallpaper-android).

Hope it will help you get started.

Comment: I have sdk not ndk with eclipse. Shall i install ndk for it?

Comment: Yes you need to setup NDK.