# Video Live wallpaper android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am trying to implement https://github.com/frankandrobot/GLWallpaperVideoDemo but this is 3 year old code. I didn't find any other tutorial. I am using eclipse on windows 7. I have searched on `google` and found that `NDK-r7` versions and later can also be build on windows without using `Cygwin`. I have also followed this link [How to play video as live wallpaper android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256412/how-to-play-video-as-live-wallpaper-android). I have generated .so files as well but when i try to install this in my device It is getting crashed. I have installed NDK also tried to replace latest `FFMpeg` libraries but no Luck! I wonder if someone could help me out of these? Error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service frankandrobot.glwallpapervideodemo.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using the linux system and i followed all the process to build NDK and libraries step by step.
And finally solved my problem.

Comment: how you solved your errors can you share it here please? i have same issues